# Confirmar eliminar un registro con funciones

Tags: php

mi problema es que necesito hacer una especie de alert que pregunte si de verdad quiere ejecutar la accion ¿como podria integrarlo al código?

```
este es el front end
echo " <td><a href='eliminar_prod.php?CodigoUsuario=".$fila['CodigoUsuario']."'> <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</button> </a></td>";
 esta funcion es back end
function EliminarProducto($no)
{
    include 'conexion.php';

    $sentencia="DELETE FROM libros WHERE NombreLibro='".$no."' ";
    $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al eliminar".mysqli_error($conexion));

}
```

Comment: ¿En back o en frontend?

Comment: cualquiera de las dos me funciona amigo, ya edite la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar agrega un onclick en el botón eliminar con la confirmación (yo cambie las comillas simples por comillas y viceversa en mi ejemplo):

```
echo '<td><a href="eliminar_prod.php?CodigoUsuario='.$fila['CodigoUsuario'].'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm(\'¿Realmente desea eliminar?\')">Eliminar</button> </a></td>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Con javascript sería algo así:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="Confirmar('1')"> 
        Eliminar 
</a>
```

Donde 1, es el CodigoUsuario, lo agregarías con php.

Luego, antes de la etiqueta body el javascript:

```
<script>
        function Confirmar(codigo)
        {
            var opcion = confirm("Desea eliminar el usuario?");
            if(opcion == true){
                location.href = "eliminar_prod.php?CodigoUsuario="+codigo;
            }else{
                return false;
            }            
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, pues en backend. ¿Qué te parece algo así?

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['op']))
    echo '<a href="?op=borrar">Borrar</a>';
else{
    if($_GET['op']=='borrar'){
        echo '¿Estás seguro? ';
        echo '<a href="?op=borrar_confirmado">Sí</a> ';
        echo '<a href=".">No</a> ';
    }
    if($_GET['op']=='borrar_confirmado'){
        echo 'Aquí sí que ya puedo borrar. ';
        echo '<a href=".">Volver</a> ';
    }
}
```

La idea es que, si se pulsa sobre borrar, no borre directamente. Sino que haga una comprobación intermedia antes de proceder al borrado.

Bien, pues esa comprobación intermedia se obtiene al recibir la instrucción desde `borrar_confirmado` en vez de `borrar`. Un primer aviso que inicia el procedimiento y un segundo aviso que hace que se ejecute la instrucción definitiva de borrado.